# Constrain Rectangle within Rectangle

Tags: java, rectangles

I am using Java's `Rectangle` class in a program.

I have two `Rectangle` objects:

```
Rectangle big = new Rectangle(...);
Rectangle small = new Rectangle(...);
```

The specific sizes of the rectangles are not important. However, `big` will always be larger than `small` (in *both* width and height).

Usually, `small` is entirely contained within `big`. I can use `Rectangle#contains` to verify this. However, when this is not the case, I would like to **move** `small` to be entirely contained within `big`. The dimensions of neither rectangle should change.

For example:

[image: Rectangles Example]

I know could use four conditionals with `Math.max` and `Math.min`, but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: There are four conditions that you have to check, so I'm not sure you can get away without a "bunch of conditionals"...

Comment: True... but I was looking for perhaps an elegant single-line expression, perhaps using the `Rectangle` class. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: A ternary expression would be "little" bit cleaner or shorter.

Comment: You gotta check bounds. Even if `Rectangle` had a method that handled this for you, it'll be checking the bounds under the hood. You could always extend upon `Rectangle` to add the functionality; create your own private `isWithinBounds` and `align` methods, then have a public `addSquare` or `placeSquare` method which checks if the rectangle is within the bounds, then align if not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with only `Math.max` and `Math.min`. Try something like this:

```
small.setLocation(
    Math.max(Math.min(small.getX(),big.getX() - small.getWidth()),big.getX()),
    Math.max(Math.min(small.getY(),big.getY() - small.getHeight()),big.getY())
);
```

You'd have to consider readability though.

Comment: hmm, that's what I feared. I thought perhaps I could use an inversion of the intersection... maybe not.

Comment: It's more compact, but not what one would call "elegant"

Comment: Yeah, I'd personally just go with the standard quadruple-ifs since that is always used for bounds checking, so a programmer that needs to maintain it should quickly recognise it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a stronger design. If you extend upon the `Rectangle` class, you can add the exact functionality you're looking for. Apparently the "big rectangle" should act as a *container*, containing the smaller rectangle:

```
class BigRectangle extends Rectangle {
    //reference to or list of rectangle(s) here

    private boolean isAlignedWith(Rectangle rect) {
        return /* bounds logic */;
    }

    private void align(Rectangle rect) {
        //move rectangle to proper position
    }

    public void add(Rectangle rect) {
        if(!isAlignedWith(rect)) {
            align(rect);
        }

        //store in reference or add to list
    }
}
```

Now, you can simply add the smaller rectangle to the bigger one:

```
Rectangle smallRectangle = new Rectangle();
BigRectangle bigRectangle = new BigRectangle();
bigRectangle.add(smallRectangle); //automatically aligns if needed
```

You are now hiding the (needed) logic, keeping your central unit of code clean. This is my opinion of the most elegant way to handle this. (*I would also probably create an interface `RectangleContainer` or `ShapeContainer`, having `BigRectangle` implement that. The interface would contain a method `add(Rectangle)` or `add(SmallShape)`*)